# multi instance of a custom polymer-element and javascript dom manipulation

Tags: polymer

I have created a custom polymer component that is a chat component. When a message is posted, a fake answer is published. Nothing very complicated.

Besides, when I instantiate two instances of my component, when I click on the enter button to post a message, the instance of the textfield used to get the text is not the good one.

I don't know if it is a problem of my code or the way I code the component or the regular behavior with polymer.

Please, let me know what is going wrong.

Best regads,

here the code:

```
<link rel="import" href="../../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<!-- css import --> <!-- ... -->

 <polymer-element name="chat-element">
<template>
    <div class="chatview containerwindow" >
        <div class="containertitle">
            <span>CHAT VIEW</span>
        </div>
        <div class="chatcomponent">
            <div id="messagecontainer" class="messagecontainer" >

            </div>
            <div class="footer">
                <input type="text" class="inputtext" id="inputtextfield" />
                <div class="insertchatbutton" id="insertchatbutton" >Enter</div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
<script>

    Polymer('chat-element', {
        myself: "",
        inputextfiled: "",
        insertchatbutton: "",
        messagecontainer: "",

        domReady: function() {
            myself = this;

            inputextfiled = this.$.inputtextfield;
            inputextfiled.onkeyup = function(event) {
                if (event.which == 13) {
                    myself.insertMessage(this);
                }
            };
            insertchatbutton = this.$.insertchatbutton;
            insertchatbutton.onclick = function() {
                myself.insertMessage(inputextfiled);
            };

            messagecontainer = this.$.messagecontainer;

        },

        insertMessage : function (textview) {
                   var div = document.createElement('div');
              div.classList.add('chatpushed');
              var span = document.createElement('span');
              span.innerHTML = textview.value;
              div.appendChild(span);

              messagecontainer.appendChild(div);

              //scroll to the bottom
              messagecontainer.scrollTop = messagecontainer.scrollHeight;

              textview.value = "";

              setTimeout(self.reply, 1000);
          },

    reply : function() {
        var div = document.createElement('div');
        div.classList.add('chatreceived');
        var span = document.createElement('span');
        span.innerHTML = "Message received";
        div.appendChild(span);

        messagecontainer.appendChild(div);
    }
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, here is a working version using more Polymer idioms:

http://jsbin.com/xokar/9/edit

Now, about some of the problems you are having. When you write

`inputextfiled = this.$.inputtextfield`

because you didn't use `var` you created a global variable. That means there is only one value of `inputextfiled` (sic) for the entire application.

You have to use `this` keyword to create and access instance variables, e.g., `this.inputextfield`.

You have a related problem here: `setTimeout(self.reply, 1000);`, because you instructed the timeout to call the `self.reply` function with `window` as `this`. You really want something like `setTimeout(self.reply.bind(self))`.

Here is some general information about `this`: http://www.quirksmode.org/js/this.html.